# how to know what item removed/unselected from multi-select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using jQuery multi-select plugin (chosen).  When an item is removed/unselected from the dropdown then I need to know what item(text/value) was unselected/removed.
I used .last() but that did not work.

Please see below code:)

```js
 var removeditems=[];
        $('#myselect').on('change',function() {
           
           removeditems.push($("#myselect").find('option:not(:selected)').last().val());
        });
```

```html
<select id="muselect">
<option value="1">option1</option>
<option value="2">option2</option>
<option value="3">option3</option>
<option value="4">option4</option>
<option value="5">option5</option>
</select>
```

This keeps giving me the unselected last value.

Comment: yeah thanks @HereticMonkey:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#myselect').on('change', function() {
  var $sel = $(this),
    val = $(this).val(),
    $opts = $sel.children(),
    prevUnselected = $sel.data('unselected');
  // create array of currently unselected 
  var currUnselected = $opts.not(':selected').map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get();
  // see if previous data stored
  if (prevUnselected) {
      // create array of removed values        
      var unselected = currUnselected.reduce(function(a, curr) {
        if ($.inArray(curr, prevUnselected) == -1) {
          a.push(curr)
        }
        return a
      }, []);
      // "unselected" is an array
      if(unselected.length){
        alert('Unselected is ' + unselected.join(', '));  
      }

  }
  $sel.data('unselected', currUnselected)
}).change();
```

the above is perfectly  working.

Comment: this one works perfectly fine, thanks to @charlietfl